# Cygwin command forwarding?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to configure my Cygwin64 terminal to do certain existing commands using shorter keywords. For example, I want to be able to use `clear` by typing `clr` in all cases. However, I still want the original `clear` to work. Is this type of command "forwarding" possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as command aliasing:

```
alias clr=clear
```

Both `clr` and `clear` will work

I hope this helps!